# After a few days of use, SATA HDD not detected until I fully switch off for a few hours

Tags: hard-drive, boot, motherboard, bios

This problem first occurred about six months ago, but has become steadily more common and is now happening every couple of days.

When I turn on my computer after shutting down, the hard drive is not recognised by the BIOS when I switch it back on. I see a single flashing cursor on the top line of the screen, for perhaps 20 seconds before the BIOS screen comes up. About a minute later, the cursor comes back, on the second line rather than the first. If I open BIOS setup, the HDD is not shown. If I open boot options, it is also not shown.

If it was asleep, it will try to wake up for around 20 seconds then give up and restart, then do the same as in the above paragraph.

I've tried all manner of things which others seem to have had success wtih - unplugging everything from the computer, switching off the PSU and holding down the power button to clear the charge, nothing. Different SATA ports and different SATA cables, nothing. Unplugging and replugging, nothing. Unplugging all USB cables when powering up, nothing.

The only thing that fixes it is turning off the computer, switching off the PSU and waiting anywhere from 2-8 hours whereupon the computer boots as normal - and if it was asleep, resumes exactly where it was when I put it to sleep, despite the restart in the middle.

**The really baffling things**: when I run a SeaTools full scan or chkdsk, I am informed that the drive has no errors and is running fine. So I assume it must be the SATA controller on the motherboard, but when I plug in my old hard drive (6 years old now and prone to making odd noises) it boots up absolutely fine.

The hard drive is very new - I got it back in July. It's a Seagate Barracuda 1317, 2TB. Fortunately it's still in warranty but I'd rather not do without it for the week they'll take to send me a new one, if it's not a problem with the hard drive. I'd also rather not shell out for a new motherboard if that turns out to be fine.

So is the problem the motherboard? The hard drive? Something else entirely?

EDIT: Something else worth noting: sometimes when the screen turns off and back on again the colours are wonky - not quite negative, but the red appears as blue, the blue as red and the yellow as light blue. This has happened on and off for years and is usually fixed by putting the computer to sleep and waking it up again - but of course that is no longer an option. This probably isn't relevant but I thought I'd mention it just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Backup your disk before doing any of the following.

- Make sure no loose metal parts are creating a short on your motherboard.
- If your system has motherboard RAID, and it's enabled, it could be problematic.  Disable it (you may need to reinstall your operating system).  A BIOS/UEFI update from your motherboard manufacturer may resolve it.
- If your system has "Intel Rapid Restore", try disabling it or updating the Windows drivers for it.
- If you recently made hardware changes to the motherboard, such as changing/adding a graphics card, or changing/adding RAM, try undoing those changes to see if a problematic component could be causing the issue.
- Try connecting system to a different power outlet.  If your computer is sharing an outlet with something that draws a lot of power, use a different circuit.
- Try swapping the PSU with a different one.  Bad power can cause weird issues such as this.
- Look on the Seagate website and see if there is a firmware update available for your drive.  If you get to this point you should update your motherboard BIOS/UEFI as well.
- Inspect your motherboard closely for any damaged components, replacement is needed if you find any issues.
- You would need to put the drive in a USB enclosure or other system for a long time to test if the drive itself is causing the issue.  If not, you need to replace your motherboard or try getting a PCIe SATA card and bypassing your motherboard's faulty SATA controller.  If you do this, disable your motherboard's onboard SATA controller in the BIOS/firmware setup menu.